# C++ omp code working on only one thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm new on OpenMP programming and I have one problem. I have found a simple code example that uses OpenMP. The code build is successful but code runs on just one thread. There is a code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    int nProcessors=omp_get_max_threads();

    std::cout<<nProcessors<<std::endl;


    omp_set_num_threads(nProcessors);
    std::cout<<omp_get_num_threads()<<std::endl;


#pragma omp parallel for 
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        int tid=omp_get_thread_num();
        std::cout<<tid<<"\t tid"<<std::endl;
        int nThreads=omp_get_num_threads();
        std::cout<<nThreads<<"\t nThreads"<<std::endl;
    }


    exit(0);

}
```

And it returns that results:

```
4
1
0        tid
1        nThreads
0        tid
1        nThreads
0        tid
1        nThreads
0        tid
1        nThreads
0        tid
1        nThreads
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Anyone can help me what I'm doing wrong? By the way I'm using Intel i5 CPU.

Comment: What compiler and OS is used? In Windows, VC++, OMP may give strange results if `omp.h` is included, but OMP support is not enabled in the project properties.

Comment: @AlexFarber, I don't think the results are strange if OpenMP is not enabled in MSVC. The results are what you would expect tid=0, and nThreads=1. I wish GCC had a way to enable the runtime functions without enabled OpenMP (ICC can do this as well).

Comment: I'm working with visual studio 2012 (visual c++ 11.0) and OS is Windows 7 Ultimate SP1

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex,

I found a solution, everything what I need to do is to enable OMP in project properties:

Project Properties >> C/C++ >> Language >> Open MP Support = YES